# Not able to detect collision with Phaser.IO

Tags: collision-detection, game-physics, phaser-framework

I am building a simple infinite runner game with Phaser.io. 
[image]
I have a rider and the rider object keeps moving right. 
Several obstacles come in its way. I want to detect when a collision takes place. But I do not seem to be able to detect any collision or overlap. Please help!

Some of my code snippets are below -

```
function create () {
    //obstacles initialization

    obstacles = game.add.group();
    obstacles.enableBody = true;

    //player initialization

    player = game.add.sprite(10, 250, 'tuktuk'); game.physics.arcade.enable(player);
    player.body.bounce.y = 0.2;
    player.body.gravity.y = 800;
    player.body.bounce.x = 0.2;
    player.body.collideWorldBounds = true;
    player.animations.add('right', [0,1,2], 20, true);
    create_random_obstacle();
    game.physics.arcade.enable(obstacles);
    game.world.bringToTop(player);
    game.physics.arcade.overlap(obstacles, player, after_collision, null, null);    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Along with B. Naeem's answer:

```
game.physics.arcade.overlap(obstacles, player, after_collision, null, null);
```

Should be in update(), as it has to check for the overlap at every frame.

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable physics first before you can check for any collisions between sprites. You can do that by

`game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);`

You should also enable the physics for the player sprite

`game.physics.arcade.enable(player);`

Comment: Thanks. I had done that. I missed to write it in the question. Amended that.

Answer (score 1):

I think you also need to enable physics on the player sprite.

```
game.physics.arcade.enable(player);
```

Also, in my game I set the first parameter of `overlap` as the sprite, and the second parameter is the group. Although it shouldn't matter according to the [Phaser docs](http://phaser.io/docs/2.4.4/Phaser.Physics.Arcade.html#overlap), but you could try just to be sure.

Comment: Thanks. I had done that. I missed to write it in the question. Amended that.